# How oozie handle dependencies?

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I have several questions about oozie 2.3 share libraries:

Currently, I defined the share libraries in our coordinator.properties:

```
oozie.use.system.libpath=true 
oozie.libpath=<hdfs_path>
```

Here are my questions:

1. When share libraries are copied to other data node and how many data node will get share libraries?
2. Are the share libraries copied to other data node based on number of wf in a coordinator job or they are only copied once per coordinator job?

Answer (score 8):

Adding entries to the `oozie.libpath` property effectively means that OOZIE will configure those libraries to be in the `mapred.cache.files` configuration property (this is a DistributedCache property) when the actions in your workflow are executed.

Hadoop will then take care of copying those jars to each cluster node once per job, and the tasks are then configured with the jar in the classpath configuration property `mapred.job.classpath.files`

So in response to your second question, they will be copied over for each action in the workflow, not once per coordinator job. So if you have a wf job that has 4 mapreduce actions, the libraries will be copied to each tasktracker (only those task trackers that participate in the mapreduce job) 4 times in the lifetime of that workflow.

Comment: Is that possible to update multiple actions or wfs to share the same distributed cache?

Comment: Not sure i understand what you're asking

Comment: I understand it means that dependencies from the system libpath will be loaded from HDFS always and avoid using distributed cache each time the workflow executes, is that so?

Comment: @TerminalUser that's a nature of hadoop job submission. nothing to do with oozie. One workaround is that you submit one job that trigger your other jobs upon completion but that's a very bad idea breaching standard methodology